# Daily Climatology in Xarray with leap years accounted for

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have some daily atmospheric data in an xarray `DataArray` and I would like to calculate the daily climatology of this data. The daily climatology is calculated by taking the same day from each year and averaging it, for example, to get the daily climatology of `01 Jan`, you take all the data corresponding to `01 Jan` from all the available years and average it.
Usually, it can be done with the `groupby` method of `DataArray` like the following:

```
da=xr.open_dataarray('some_daily_data_2000-2020.nc')
daily_clim=u.groupby('time.dayofyear').mean()
```

Except that it doesn't properly handle leap years. The `dayofyear` values change between leap year and non-leap year, as illustrated below:

```
da.sel(time=slice('2020-02-27', '2020-03-02')).indexes['time'].dayofyear
da.sel(time=slice('2019-02-27', '2019-03-02')).indexes['time'].dayofyear
```

The output is:

```
Int64Index([58, 59, 60, 61, 62], dtype='int64', name='time')
Int64Index([58, 59, 60, 61], dtype='int64', name='time')
```

As seen in the output, **02-Mar** is the 62th day of a leap year while it is the 61th day of a non-leap year. That is, grouping on `dayofyear` cannot handle leap years and would produce incorrect results in this case.
Is there a proper method or a workaround to calculate daily climatology this in Xarray, with leap years accounted for?

Comment: Maybe make a string with the day and month but not the year, and use day-month in the groupby?

Comment: +1 to @TMBailey's suggestion.  For more discussion of this and another alternative solution, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1844#issuecomment-417855365).